# How to get month name from partition time in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I need to extract month number from current_date() in BigQquery. I am using below sql statement that extracts month name .How to get month number:

Select MONTH(current_date())

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [EXTRACT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract) to extract month number from date:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE())
```

Try [FORMAT_TIMESTAMP](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp) to extract month name from timestamp:

```
SELECT FORMAT_TIMESTAMP('%B', _PARTITIONTIME) FROM tablename
```

Comment: sorry i have asked wrong question. yes you are right this works.What  about my updated question